# Different results on same MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT visitorIP
  FROM visitors
 WHERE visitDate BETWEEN '2018-08-18 00:00:00 ' AND '2018-08-19 20:32:03'    
 ORDER 
    BY visitDate DESC
```

and this gives me 529 items (IP addresses) as the result. I have broken down the time period to the following chunks which covers exactly the same as the one used in the above statement:

```
2018-08-18 00:00:00 ~ 2018-08-19 00:00:00 and 
 2018-08-19 00:00:00 ~ 2018-08-19 20:32:03
```

and queries them with the same SQL statement, for the first one I get 544 results and for the second one I get 36! which surprisingly their sum is not 529 (GREATER THAN ACTUAL RESULT!!!) at all.

How can I fix it?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Is there any records in 2018-08-19 00:00:00 ?

Comment: This question needs schema, sample data and the actual code you used for the two queries mentioned.

Comment: @M4HdYaR - `BETWEEN` is inclusive so if anything the two smaller queries should yield more results if that were the case

Comment: @billynoah Perhaps the OP is a bit confused

Comment: perhaps, it's hard to say since the question can only draw speculation.  But your answer below was my first thought as well...

Comment: We can't replicate the result, so it seems we cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(my_int INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_int BETWEEN 2 AND 8;
+--------+
| my_int |
+--------+
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |
|      5 |
|      6 |
|      7 |
|      8 |
+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_int BETWEEN 2 AND 4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_int BETWEEN 4 AND 8;    
+--------+
| my_int |
+--------+
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |
|      4 |
|      5 |
|      6 |
|      7 |
|      8 |
+--------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: See my comment above - since `BETWEEN` is inclusive, the two queries should produce *more* results rather than fewer as you've just demonstrated.  In his question he claims he's getting *fewer* total results so this doesn't really provide an explanation

Comment: Seems it is the case since the results is greater than the first query, if it is the case how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above this question can only draw speculation given what you've provided.  That said, here is a simple method for debugging head scratchers like this when they come up:

```
SELECT visitorIP
  FROM visitors
 WHERE visitDate BETWEEN '2018-08-18 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-19 20:32:03'
    AND visitorIP NOT IN (
        # query 1
        UNION ALL
        # query 2
    )
 ORDER 
    BY visitDate DESC
```

If there are results in the first query that aren't showing up the the two subqueries, this will reveal what they are and from there you should be able to determine where the error in your logic is happening.